# Why Dart generics don't use the actual instance type to create parent?

Tags: flutter, dart, generics

Let's say I have this class:

```dart
class Class<T extends num> {
  const Class(this.n);
  final T n;
  
  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Class<$T>(n: $n<${n.runtimeType}>)';
  }
}
```

When I run this code:

```dart
for (final n in <num>[0.3, 2, -4]) {
  final instance = Class(n);
  print('$instance');
}
  
final instance = Class(1);
print('$instance');
```

I get this output:

```dart
Class<num>(n: 0.3<double>)
Class<num>(n: 2<int>)
Class<num>(n: -4<int>)
Class<int>(n: 1<int>)
```

Why doesn't Dart use the actual type of the number? Why use the `List` generic?

Comment: Type arguments for generics and type inference is done at *compilation-time*.  They can use only *statically* known types, not runtime types.

Comment: maybe you just want `.runtimeType` or `is`

Comment: @jamesdlin could you please write an answer for me to mark this as solved?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh thanks for the suggestions, but I'm quite familiar with those already. My question was more focused on understanding the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type arguments for generics (and similarly, type inference) are handled at *compilation-time*.  They can use only *statically* known times, not runtime types.  For example, `Class<n.runtimeType>` is not valid.

When you iterate over your `List<num>`, each element *n* is statically known only to be a `num`, so `Class(n)` is inferred to be `Class<num>`.

When you use `Class(1)`, `1` is an `int` literal, so the type of the expression is inferred to be `Class<int>`.